# useNativeControl with Expo Video component causing app to crash

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi I am trying to use video with React Native and came across Expo Video Component (see https://docs.expo.io/versions/v14.0.0/sdk/video.html) and as I am using create-react-native-app to setup my app I thought this would be a good option. However when I add "useNativeControl to my video component it causes my app to crash.

Here is some code with useNativeControl: //displays just the controls for a second and then says "Expo has stopped" before exiting app

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo';

    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.app}>
           <Video  source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }} rate={1.0} volume={1.0} useNativeControls muted={false}  resizeMode="cover"  shouldPlay isLooping style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }} />
           </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Here is the code without it:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { Video } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
        <Header />
        <Topics />
                <Video  source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }} rate={1.0} volume={1.0} muted={false}  resizeMode="cover"  shouldPlay isLooping style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

so as you can see the only difference is the "useNativeControls", without usenativecontrols the app works fine, I just don't have any controls on the video.

Main Question: How can I use native controls and not have my app crash?

Side Note/Question:
Alternatively, is there another video player that is simple to use for beginners of react-native? I have spent a few hours on this but haven't come up with a solution yet. I originally tried react-native-video (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video), but this did not work for me (and judging from the docs it requires you to make changes to java code which is not something I am looking to do). So if there is an alternative to expo's video component that has controls and works without any java/swift knowledge that is what I am looking for.

Edit:

package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^20.0.0",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.46.4",
    "react-native-video": "^2.0.0",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ejected/detached your app? That library needs some native code to be added to a project. You cannot use it with plug&play method. Read more about detaching here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html

Be warned though, it's wild world once you start building an app for yourself. I am there by myself right now and failing wonderfully. I doubt you can find any video player that would not require some native code to be added.